# How to make an up and down arrow

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

How can **draw an up-down arrow** with pure *CSS*?

This is what I get using *HTML* :

```css
.up-down-arrow {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #666;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="up-down-arrow">&#8597;</div>
```

But the line between the arrows is too short. Can I make it longer?

Ideally, this is what I am after:

[image: Up down arrows with a line in between]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make the **up-down arrows** with the line in between the same as your example, I would suggest using SVG. You can use it inline as shown in the following example :

```css
.wrap{
position:relative;
  height:70vh;
  border-left:1px solid #000;
  margin:10vh 50px;
  padding:5vh 20px;
}
.arrow {
  position:absolute;
  left:-5px;
  width: 9px;
  height: auto;
}
.up{top:-9px;}
.down{bottom:-9px;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <svg class="arrow up" viewbox="0 0 7 10">
    <path d="M3.5 0 L7 10 Q3.5 7 0 10z"/>
  </svg>
  <svg class="arrow down" viewbox="0 0 7 10">
    <path d="M3.5 10 L7 0 Q3.5 3 0 0z"/>
  </svg>
  Whatever content you need here
</div>
```

The inline SVG arrows are made with a path element and using one [quadratic curve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) (made with `Q3.5 7 0 10` in the up arrow).
The line between the arrows is made with a border left on a container `div` it expands with the height of this container.
Both arrows are positioned absolutely.

Comment: thanks! how can I adjust the width of the arrow heads? need them to be wider.

Comment: @teelou you just need to change the width of the `.arrow` elements. And adjust the `left` property to center them.

Comment: also, how do I change the colour of the arrow heads?

Comment: @teelou to change the arrow colour, you can use the `fill` property like this : https://jsfiddle.net/2w5v6zL3/ Other than that, nothing special about inline svg.

Answer (score 9):

**Single element solution**

You can achieve that with [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), [CSS triangles](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) and some [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

```css
.arrow {
  width: 2px;
  height: 200px; /* <- adjust your height as you need it */
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -9px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.arrow::before {
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}

.arrow::after {
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

**Multiple elements solution**

To achieve the actual arrow shape, you will need multiple elements. Here the pseudo elements are used to create white triangles, that cut out the black arrow heads:

```css
.arrow {
  width: 2px;
  height: 200px; /* <- adjust your height as you need it */
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.up, .down, .arrow::before, .arrow::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.up {
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}

.down {
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
}

.arrow::before, .arrow::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 2;
}
.arrow::before {
  top: 11px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
}
.arrow::after {
  bottom: 11px;
  border-top: 4px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="up"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="down"></div>
</div>
```

Or another variant with a continuous line:

```css
.line {
  position: relative;
  margin: -15px 0 -15px 9px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 5;
}

.up,
.down {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.up {
  border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}

.down {
  border-top: 15px solid black;
}

.down::before, .up::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  content: '';
  z-index: 4;
}
.down::before {
  bottom: 11px;
  border-top: 4px solid white;
}
.up::after {
  top: 11px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="up"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="down"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can I make the arrow heads curve inside as the picture?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one more solution using arrow char code `\027A4` for `::before` and `::after` content.

Size of these chars has bound to root font size `rem` and their modification `rotate`, `top` and `left` based on the content font-size.

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 3px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: tomato;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  content: '\027A4';
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: tomato;
}

.arrow::before {
  top: -.9em;
  left: -.5em;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.arrow::after {
  bottom: -.9em;
  left: -.32em;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: I think just Vivaldi isn't properly ajusted for my arrow heads.

Answer (score 3):

To keep it simple, change the height style in **mid** class to increase the length of line!

```css
.up {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: none;
}
.mid {
  margin-left:7px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color:black;
}
.down{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 10px solid black;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='up'></div>
<div class='mid'></div>
<div class='down'></div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks. can I make the arrow heads curve inside just as the picture?